# Searching for words with specific format in Microsoft Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation, interop, ranorex

I'm working with  Windows 10 Enterprise, Ranorex 8.1.1 and Microsoft Word 2010. My objective is to find all the words in a document (Microsoft Word) that fulfill a specific format, which is: red and underlined or red and strike-through. See some examples in the picture I've attached.
First of all, I've tried to perform it by means of Ranorex Spy, adding class name to GPI capture list. However, Spy can't detect every word, it seems to detect some kind of text blocks whose pattern is unknown for me. As well as not detecting word by word, I can't see the properties involving underlined and strike-through, I just can see the color property. Has Ranorex got something to perform that?

My alternative has been to use some code in C# adapted to Microsoft, like explained in msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we.aspx and learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects 
I've managed to do researches by words, although not by color, underlined or strike-through properties. For the color research:

```
[language=csharp]Word.Range auxrng = myDocument.Content;
auxrng.Find.ClearFormatting();
auxrng.Find.Forward = true; 
auxrng.Find.Font.ColorIndex=Word.WdColorIndex.wdRed; //red color search.
auxrng.Select(); // It is selecting the whole previous range, no distinction for the first red word
auxrng.Find.Execute("");
auxrng.Find.Font.Underline=Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;              
auxrng.Select(); /it is selecting the whole previous range again
auxrng.Find.Execute("");[/language]
```

Before this code, I had written previous code to communicate Ranorex and Microsoft Word, no problems with that.

```
[language=csharp]Word.Application wordApp = new Word.ApplicationClass();
Word.Document myDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open(wordComparedFilePath);
wordApp.Visible = true;[/language]
```

Even, as said, I've managed to define ranges starting by a specific searched word and ending with another word.
Regarding the strike-through words, I haven't found a code for searching them, just this: auxrng.Find.Font.Underline.StrikeThrough
I'm afraid this method returns a boolean but does not modify the range.
I would appreciate very much if someone could help me on this. If you need more files or information, ask me ;)

Thakn you in advance

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response! I'm not sure about using Find.Text = "". Yes, my intention is to search every word that is red and underlined or red and strikethrough, that's why I've used "". Should I use Find.Text = "" as a single line of the code or as a parameter within Find.Execute? Reading the Find.Execute method in [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.execute.aspx [/link] , I'm wondering if you want me to write Find.Text="" as the ref object FindText.
I've tried both ways and Ranorex has warned me that Find.Text cannot be invoked.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough :( My objective is to know automatically if there is any difference between two documents and get those words causing differences. I'm running automatic tests with documents created by an app, using Ranorex to run the tests and create reports (success/failure). Therefore,knowing that the Compare tool of Microsoft Word creates red and underlined/strikethrough words for the differences,I've written code to search words of this format. However,my algorithm cannot detect them, but it can detect words of these features if I create them by myself.

Comment: Assuming what you're doing has full access to Word's object model ("interop") what you need is a different set of objects. Start your research with the `Revisions` collection and the `Revision` object. Basically, you can foreach `Document.Revisions` and test the `Type` (returns a Word.WdRevisionType enum) as well as get its `Range`.

Comment: Hi Cindy! Thank you again for your help. While reading your comment, I've seen a very useful thread in stackoverflow which has helped me a lot, too.Finally, this code is working for me:
[language=csharp]

foreach (Word.Revision rngrevision in rng.Revisions)
      {
       if (rngrevision.Type != Word.WdRevisionType.wdNoRevision)
              {
               foundword=true;
               Report.Log(ReportLevel.Failure, rngrevision.Range.Text + " causes a difference of the type: " + rngrevision.Type);  
              }
              else {
              }
      }

[/language]

Comment: Seeing as how the actual problem turned out to be something entirely different from the question, I'm going to mark the question to be closed as "not reproducible". Just so you're not surprised when, eventually, it gets closed :-) Good work tracking everything down and getting it going!